# drawing open balls for the radar screen metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

What do the unit balls of this metric look like for radii 1/2, 1 and 3/2 please ?

Radar screen metric is $d(x,y):= \min(1, \|x - y\|_2)$, where the subscript $2$ after the last $\|$ indicates it's over $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Also, [see this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for an explanation of how to write math here.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

- The metric $d$ is identical to the usual metric when $\|x-y\|\le 1$; what does that tell you about the $d$-balls of radii $\frac12$ and $1$?
- Now let $x\in\Bbb R^2$ be arbitrary. The open $d$-ball of radius $\frac32$ centred at $x$ contains those points $y\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $d(x,y)<\frac32$. Can you find any point $y\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $d(x,y)$ is **not** less than $\frac32$?

Comment: So the balls of radii 1/2 and 1 are concentric balls at x whereas the ball of radius 3/2 (ie 1.5 ) is off the screen as its out of range ? ...ie its bigger than min (1, ||x-y||) ?

Comment: @Des: Since $\min\{1,\|x-y\|\}$ is not a single number, but rather (for fixed $x$) a function of $y$, it doesn’t make sense to say that some ball is bigger than that. Look at the definition of $B\left(x,\frac32\right)$: it’s $\left\{y\in\Bbb R^2:d(x,y)<\frac32\right\}$. What subset of $\Bbb R^2$ is that?

Comment: Sorry .....you have lost me. The question said "draw the unit balls of radii 1/2, 1 , 3/2 "....which in itself seems contradictory cos if its a unit ball how can it have a radius other than 1 ?

Comment: @Des: The question is internally inconsistent. The unit ball must indeed have radius one, so it’s impossible to draw the unit ball of radius $\frac12$ or $\frac32$. Some part of the question must therefore be in error. It’s most likely that the word *unit* is the mistake, and that you’re intended to draw the balls of radii $\frac12,1$, and $\frac32$.

Comment: You are correct ....i checked with the author and it is a mistake ....should just say draw the balls of radii 1/2,1 and 1.5 ....that being the case they would just be concentric circles of radii 1/2, 1 and 1.5 in R 2  ....right ?

Comment: @Des: That’s correct for the first two, but not for the third. **Every** point of $\Bbb R^2$ is inside the $d$-ball of radius $\frac32$ centred at the origin.

Comment: Brian - thank you. I am thinking the reason that every point is inside the d ball of radius 1.5 is because of the min(1,etc ) right ? ...ie the metric takes the min value in this case as the value 1.5 > 1  ?

Comment: @Des: Yes, that’s right: the $\frac32$-ball centred at any point is the whole plane.